# Implementing ld+json using Nuxt and __dangerouslyDedableSanitizers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am Using nuxt.js and need to use structured data for google using ld+json

I'm going to use dynamic data in which i've populated and have run this through JSON.stringify method.

Am I using this correctly for XXS Scripting? Also do I need to pass the __dangerouslyDisableSanitizers as I'm not sure on the docs that have been provided?

```
head(){
    let user = this.user;
    return {
        title: 'This is my page title',
        meta: [
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'This is my description' }
        ],
        script: [
            {
                innerHTML: JSON.stringify({
                    '@context': 'http://schema.org',
                    '@type': 'Website',
                    'url': `${user}`
                }), 
                type: 'application/ld+json'
            }
        ],
        __dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script']
    }
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

But since vue-meta v2.1 used by Nuxt.js, the `JSON.stringify` and `__dangerouslyDisableSanitizers` are useless if you use the `json` property:

```
head(){
    let user = this.user;
    return {
        title: 'This is my page title',
        meta: [
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'This is my description' }
        ],
        script: [
            {
                json: {
                    '@context': 'http://schema.org',
                    '@type': 'Website',
                    'url': `${user}`
                }, 
                type: 'application/ld+json'
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

see vue-meta docs: https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#add-json-data

Comment: Ok Thanks.....I end up with text in my json object when I view it in the source code.....Is this correct?  We&#x27;re Australia&#x27;s ....Or should it be Australia's in the source code?

Comment: Yes, it's a correct value. As explained in the docs (https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#add-json-data) your text is just sanitized: "When passing an array or object to the json property the keys and values of the variable will still be sanitized to prevent XSS"

Comment: @NicolasPennec I copy pasted json-ld sanitized text..in https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool
Looks like google didn't recognise it.

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis which version of nuxt & vute-meta did you use? (please run "npm list nuxt vue-meta"). It works fine for me with nuxt 2.12.2 (+ vue-meta 2.3.3 as children dep)

Comment: @NicolasPennec I never said that it didn't work....my point is that google is not validating the sanitized json when i tested in testing tool